# Talend tFlowMeterCatcher resets after each subjob

Tags: talend

I have 3 data flows in Talend that execute independently (in parallel), they are located in 3 subjobs.

On order to calculate the number of rows in each flow I use 3 monitored connections (one for each data flow).

I also use tFlowMeterCatcher to summarize amount of rows processes by the job:

tFlowMeterCatcher -> tAggregate -> tFileOutputDelimited

The problem is that during execution tAggregate is being invoked 3 times after completion of each abovementioned subjob, and each time tFileOutputDelimited logs 3 rows of statistics for 3 data flows (9 rows in total).

I was expecting that tAggregate will be invoked only once after full completion of the job (with all subjobs), and I'll get 1 row for each data flow (3 rows in total). Am I missing something?